# Make line in center of container, not screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make something similar to FB timeline and I need to create a line in the center of my container. Problem is that it is creating line in center of screen, not container. I need it to center on container since I have sidebar on right side which means that `.timeline` is not in center of screen.

What I want to achieve is createing pixel-perfect line in center of container that stays in center even if I zoom-in with my browser.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Evzk/

Answer (score 0):

To answer both parts of your question, setting your content to `position:relative;` will stop the divider covering your footer and will also make it central to the content rather than the window:

http://jsfiddle.net/2CLQp/1/

Comment: It works here, but for some reason does not on my live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3dvtL/ Any idea why?

Comment: Anyway, I updated my question, this fiddle was wrong, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the parent containers position to relative,

```
.content{
 float: left;
 width: 870px;
 background-color: green;
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2CLQp/2/

Comment: It works here, but for some reason does not on my live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3dvtL/ Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, then I'm pretty much screwed since I cannot predict height of that element.. ))